# Change local variable in a function from main scope without using global variables

Tags: c++

I have a function in my code of the type:

```
double f (double x, double y){
...
int entry_1 = 0;
int entry_2 = 1;
...
}
```

The values for `entry_1` and `entry_2` will change after some loops inside the function `f`. The function `f` will be used in the same way in the main script:

```
double f_value;
double y_instance = 0.5;
for (int i = 0; i<100; i++){
 ...
f_value = f(x*i, y_instance);
...
}
```

Let's suppose that after this loop, `entry_1 = 7` and `entry_2 = 0`, because they changed inside the `f` function.

If `entry_1` and `entry_2` were global variables, now I would do something like this:

```
entry_1 = 0;
entry_2 = 1;

for (int i = 0; i<100; i++){
...
f_value = f(x*i-2, y_instance);
...
}
```

I don't think is a good idea to set `entry_1` and `entry_2` as input parameters, because I would be forced to pass some value during the `for` loops in the main function. I want that `entry_1` and `entry_2` are manipulated by `f` during the `for` loops, and after those loops, reinitialize them from the main function.

Comment: please turn your snippet in a demonstrative example. Maybe you want to declare them `static` but the question is too unclear to be sure what you actually want to do

Comment: Pass them into the function by reference?

Comment: see also: [mcve]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. If you simply want to choose how to initialize `entry_1` and `entry_2` when calling the function, you can just add more parameters to `f` and provide them when calling it. If this is not what you are trying to do, you will need to elaborate.

Comment: But you are already initializing them to 0 and 1 respectively. The question is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a class, and make your program object-oriented:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    double f (double x, double y)
    {
        return x + y + entry_1; // for example.
    }
    void setEntry1(double value)
    {
        entry_1 = value;
    }
  private:
    double entry_1 = 0;
    double entry_2 = 1;
};
```

You then use it like that:

```
Foo object;
object.setEntry1(0.5);

double z = object.f(0.1, 0.2);
double z1 = object.f(0.2, 0.3);
```

That allows you to have multiple object performing *f* with different *entry* values. And to change those *entry* values.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn them into parameters of the function.
But instead of by copy, take them by reference :

```
double f (double& entry_1, double& entry_2, double x, double y)
{ ...... }
```

That way they can be stored wherever You want, but will retain the modifications between calls of the function.

But a better way would be for it to be private variables of a class.